# Checking if 2 list have any equal element Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I was trying to check if two lists have some equal element.

```
Example : 
List1 = ["John", "Thomas", "Sinclair", "Marie"]
List2 = ["Philip", "Albert", "Maria"]
```

The result should be false.

But if was like this :

```
List3 = ["John", "Thomas", "Sinclair", "Marie"]
List4 = ["Philip", "Albert", "Marie", "Edward"]
```

The result should be true, list3 e list4 have the same, "Marie".

My code :

```
import qualified Data.Text    as Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text

main = do
    list1 <- fmap Text.lines (Text.readFile "file1.txt")
    list2 <- fmap Text.lines (Text.readFile "file.txt")
    compareList list1 list2

compareList (x:xs) ys | elem x ys = True
                      |otherwise = compareList xs ys

result = 
if ((compareList list1 list2) == True)
       then putStrnLn ( " They sare elements")
          else
             putStrnLn ("They don't share elements")
```

I'm totally lost, the code does not compile.

Comment: Have you ever stopped to think about the predicate `(== True)`? What type does it have? How does it transform values?

Comment: @Carl compareList should return True or false, I'm not understanding the error.

Comment: I'm not answering your question, though. I'm making an unrelated comment on your code. It's one that is worth thinking about.

Comment: And you will also get a runtime error

Comment: @Carl The (==True) should be comparing two booleans, the function compareList should return a boolean too. So, I'm not understanding where you want to get.

Comment: @SimonH Can you explain me, why?

Comment: @user3645265 He means that `== True` is unnecessary. `compareList list1 list2` should already return a boolean, so you just need to do: `if compareList list1 list2` and be done with it.

Comment: You need a base case  -I've provided an edit to the code below as that also lacked it

Comment: @Jefffrey If he doesn't think about it, he'll never understand.

Comment: What exactly is the type of `(== True)`?  How does it transform the values it receives?  These aren't meaningless questions.  If you answer them, then think about what those answers mean, you'll understand my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this function in terms of `intersect` and `null` as follows:

```
compareList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
compareList a = not . null . intersect a
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/778930ece503bf07)

Your code is not compiling because:

1. you have a weird indentation in the definition of `result`
2. `list1` and `list2` are not defined within `result`
3. `putStrnLn` doesn't exist; you probably meant `putStrLn`
4. you are calling `compareList` in `main`, which returns `Bool`, not `IO ()`
5. you need to add an `(Eq a) =>` constraint on `compareList` as well as in `result`

If you follow these suggestions you get:

```
compareList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
compareList [] _ = False
compareList (x:xs) ys 
    | elem x ys = True
    | otherwise  = compareList xs ys

result :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> IO ()
result list1 list2 = 
    if (compareList list1 list2)
        then putStrLn ("They share elements")
        else putStrLn ("They don't share elements")
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7144f3601f6cc2ea)

Answer (score 1):

Without explicit recursion, you could use this

```
compareList :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
compareList xs ys = foldl (\acc x -> x `elem` ys || acc) False xs
```